# Getting error while trying to make writeable copy of sqlite

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I have a copy of my db in Supporting Files folder. I need update a couple of tables and I am trying to use method to make writeable copy of db.

```
- (void) createEditableDatabase
{
   BOOL success; 
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
   NSError *error;
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
   NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *writableDB = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yc_ch.db"];
   success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDB];
   NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yc_ch.db"]; 
   success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:writableDB error:&error];
   if (!success) 
   {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file:'%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
   }
}
```

I have created (typed, physically) the 'Documents' folder in the root. At moment hierarchy of docs looks like this:

[image]

When I run my app. I am getting NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file:'%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);.

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy the file even if the file already exists in the Document, I think NSFileManager copyFileAtPath: will return NO if file already exists at destination, hence failing your check and raising your NSAssert

```
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDB];
if (success)
{
    return;
}
```

So the file isn't copied over if it already exists in your document. If that's what causing the error, can you actually post the assertion, [error localizedDescription] will at least tell you what is wrong with it at the moment.

Edit:

```
- (void) createEditableDatabase
{
   BOOL success; 
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
   NSError *error;
   NSString *writableDB = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yc_ch.db"];
   NSLog(@"Document path = %@", writableDB);
   success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDB];
   if (success)
   {
       return;
   }
   NSString *defaultPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yc_ch" ofType:@"db"];
   NSLog(@"defaultPath = %@", defaultPath);
   error = nil;
   success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:writableDB error:&error];
   if (!success) 
   {
       NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
   }
   if (error)
   {
        NSLog(@"error = %@", [error localizedDescription]);
   }
}
```

Comment: It was there before, but I have deleted it already. Deleted (from computer, not reference) folder and created it again.

Comment: see my edit, replace whatever you have with the one I wrote, and if it still has error, post the log here so we can help you to see what's wrong, also, the writableDB "Documents" folder has nothing to do with your XCode project!!

Comment: Hello @X Slash. Sorry for delay. Now it says. 2012-01-20 00:23:05.728 YC[4732:207] Document path = /Users/nathan/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/A84AA87C-C022-4B82-8A71-0E1117875612/Documents/yh_ch.db
2012-01-20 00:23:05.731 YC[4732:207] defaultPath = (null)
2012-01-20 00:23:05.734 YC[4732:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil'

Comment: my apology, there is a typo on my code, your file is yc_ch.db, not yh_ch, try my code again! I edited it

Comment: Hi. It worked and and now I've got 2 dbs. One in resources and another in ApplicationSupport.....Applications.... root of Application. Which of them to use, and are they somehow related now?

Comment: do your SQL manipulation on the writableDB path, the path in defaultPath isn't writable

Comment: Well, that I do understand, but listen, at moment in my DBAccess layer class I keep the methods supposed to read data from db. This class getting initialized with NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yc_ch" ofType:@"db"]; What should I type instead of it? Also, may I remove the copy of db from resourses and remove method that copy db to documents folder?

Comment: Now I tried to alter the current path to NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yc_ch.db"];
 and now I can't read from new db.

Comment: Do not remove anything from your XCode project, nor the one in "Documents", that isn't how it supposed to work! The "yc_ch.db" you should be working on is the one in "Documents" folder, NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yc_ch" ofType:@"db"]; will return you a path to your file, but it's not writable. So how you app should work is, first, you check if "yc_ch.db" exists in "Documents", if not, copy, if it exists, don't copy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6869/discussion-between-x-slash-and-nathan)